# Jquery Validate -> fadeIn textField if specific-textFields are valid?

Tags: jquery, validation, fadein

I got stuck on a very simple Question,

I have a form in that order:

- email,
- pw1,
- pw2,
- username (which is optional)

The whole form is validated with .validate() and it´s working awesome and shows up nice error messages etc..

The one thing I couldn't achieve is : I want the Username-textfield to only show up if email, pw and pw2`s values are valid

I have the username input inner a
div class="reguser" style="display:none;"

I tried the .valid() method like :

```
if ($('#passwort').valid() && $('#passwort2').valid() && $('#email').valid()) {
    $('.reguser').show();
};
```

that doesnt work at all, all fields asked if .valid() are initially highlighted with the error message now and if they are getting valid by putting valid value in, `.reguser` doesn't show up

also tried to catch the class valid, but i guess i need to do this on an event like onfocusout or so

```
if ($('#passwort').hasClass('.valid') && $('#passwort2').hasClass('.valid') && $('#email').hasClass('.valid')) {
    $('.reguser').show();
};
```

Has anyone a hint for me ? I´m searching the Internet for hours and hours and not making progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all required fields are needed to show the username field, you can check if the whole form is valid:

```
$('#formId :input').on('blur', function(){
    if($('#formId').valid())
    {
        $('.reguser').show();
    }
});
```

You can change `blur` to the event you want.

Comment: thank you, that resolved my question, but the user flow still not is perfect, because the pw2-field is on focus and the next thing you do is not leaving the textfield but clicking submit button, i would rather show .reguser on the moment it fulfills the requirements to be valid just like the error message "6 letters required" hides when the 7th letter is typed in, anyone thinks thats possible ?

Comment: Change the blur event to keyup or keypress. Remember to keep checking this on all elements in the form (as it is now), as the user may fill it out of order.

Comment: Okay got it, just changed "blur" to "keyup" just like you said :) awesome